# Azure devops ASP.Net CI -get artifact in zip

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-artifacts

I have Asp.net CI, which publishes .zip artifacts.

When I download the .zip artifact, I have to go through many folders to be able to see the files.
I used the default arguments when building solution and many other ones, but no result.
Is there a way to publish the .zip so, that when I download it **I see the files already?**
In .net core that issue doesn't occur, but in asp.net does.

I used templated not yaml files.

> Soulution build:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

> Publish Symbols

```
steps:
- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true
```

> Publish artifact

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact WEB: to drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\HRSoft.WebClient.zip'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your msbuildArgs you should say that you want the artifacts as zip:

```
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" or /p:p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip"
```